# Using S3 instead of SQS for integration purposes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, architecture, amazon-sqs, serverless

folks.

There's a question I've recently faced, which brought some concerns and hesitations. I'm creating an "almost serverless" micro-service using AWS. Here is its workflow: [Workflows options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uADBY.png)

The thing is the input message may be large, but AWS SQS limits message size to 256 Kb. So, I decided to use S3 and S3 notifications to handle inputs: client PUTs an object; its creation triggers Lambda functions and so on. In that way, 256 Kb limits are not relevant, but on the other hand, I'm using storage service as an integration one. One of the concerns is a dead letter queue handling f.e.

Maybe someone has faced similar problems. One of the things is to keep "serverless". Are there any good solutions/improvements/advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-s3-messages.html

Comment: I've seen that. Unfortunately, Java is not an option for me here. In addition, as I see it uses S3 for objects storing. So, I can't understand if it's a good workaround or not...

Comment: It's a design pattern you could follow though. Use SQS for message queuing, but have SQS point to an S3 file for your large messages. The SQS message content's would just be a S3 URL.

Comment: Yeah, agree. Thanks @MarkB

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend combining the two approaches:

- Write the data to Amazon S3
- Create a message in the Amazon SQS queue that includes a reference to the data in S3

This way, you have the benefits of using a queue, with additional storage.

If all the data you require is already in the file, then you can configure an Amazon S3 Event to create the SQS message directly in the queue. The message will include the name of the bucket and the key of the object. Thus, putting the file in S3 will create the SQS message and trigger the AWS Lambda function. This is more scalable than directly triggering the Lambda function from S3.

Comment: Yeah, agree. That's a better solution. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Kinesis Stream, then attaching your lambda to the stream with a size of 1? You could also handle your dead-letter with shard time stamps etc.

Or if you are able to manipulate the original message place your timestamp inside the message then you can easily utilize kinesis firehose and bulk load messages. Limitation on Kinesis is 2mb so will give you almost 10x the message size on sqs which you could compress further.